# Qt application crashing on exit

Tags: c++, qt

I have a GUI written in C++ with the Qt library.  For my application I used a TreeView object.  To make the reuse of this object easy I made a templated class which my QObjects can inherit from.  Since moc cannot work with templated classes I made the class like this:

```
class Tree : public QObject, public TreeTemplate<TreeType, TreeItemType>
{
     Q_OBJECT
};
```

This allows only the Tree class to use moc (TreeTemplate does not inherit QObject or use the Q_OBJECT macro), while getting the benefits of template.

My issue is that upon exiting my application crashes, without fail (even if I call exit and skip the QApplication cleanup).  I am thinking there might be an issue with the generated classes for moc, with their "static-meta-objects"

I cannot use valgrind, due to use of `__ASM__` that it cannot process.  :-(

Does anyone know if my design of using templated Qt class (+moc) that inherits from a templated class would cause this issue?

Crash is in: libc.so after exit.

Comment: What does a gdb backtrace show?

Comment: Does adding an empty virtual destructor change anything?

Comment: Most of my crashes on exit in Qt have happened when I was doubling freeing an instance of a class. Most often this occurred when I passed a 'newed' instance of a class to a Qt container that takes ownership (i.e. the container will destroy it automatically), and then tried to destroy it in my own code.

Comment: The obvious suggestion is: instead of deriving from TreeTemplate<A,B>, aggregate it (add as a member variable). Then change the code to use the aggregate. My bet is that it will still crash. The problem is either in TreeTemplate code simply being buggy, or there are bugs elsewhere in your program. Just deriving from a QObject *and* a two-parameter template class in itself doesn't cause any problem. You have not offered an SSCCE that would reproduce it. Sorry, can't help you any further at this point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK, your approach will not work.

The `moc` is ran before the C++ preprocessor, that's why `QObject` and templated classes don't work - the preprocessor hasn't generated the classes yet.  You are templatizing the class so the `moc`'s data about the class won't match the signature of whatever template classes are created from it during the preprocessor.

Comment: Then it doesn't work.  Can you show us the last line of your code, in the backtrace, where it fails?  I appreciate that you can't use valgrind, but your debugger will at least show you where the problem is starting.

Comment: If your comment was true "the class won't match the signature of whatever template classes are created from it during the preprocessor" I'd think it wouldn't compile, which it does, and runs.  That is what I meant.  It behaves perfectly fine until destruction.

I'll get the stack trace up in a bit.